# Android Memory Leak - Static method parameters

Tags: android, memory-leaks, mat

I have a Helper class in which I have declared a couple of static methods. Some methods require a context as a parameter like the one below. Will this give me a memory leak issue ?
Kindly advice. Thanks :)

```
public static void randomMethod(final Context context, final MyFragment frag){
    //...  
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this will case memory leak issue.

Comment: As long as you're not storing that `Context` reference in a static member, it will pass out of scope when `randomMethod()` finishes executing.